# Execute HTML tag in jsp, from java variable, struts 2

Tags: java, html, jsp, struts2

I have string array list in my java code with html tags,
as a example it's like this

```
<li><input type="checkbox"><label>View_A</label>
<ul><li><input type="checkbox"><label>View_B</label></ul>
```

I want to get this to my jsp and execute it as HTML code
I used struts iterator

```
<s:iterator value="codeArr" status="statusVar">
     <s:property/><br>
</s:iterator>
```

but using this code will print on web page, I want to print HTML list

also try 
`<s:property escapeHtml="false"/>`
using this code exception will throw

How can I do this

Comment: Why you want to keep html code in your list ?

Comment: I create tree in this code for that I have to use recursion to create this list

Comment: I found the way using <s:property escape="false"/> it will work fine.   thanks! guys

Comment: Then you are using an old version of Struts2. Migrate ASAP to 2.3.24, for your own safety ;)

Comment: It's not good way to use `escape="false"`, you can use it only if you trust the value in your variable, otherwise you have a problem with CSRF protection. Struts2 itself generate a code that is protected against this security threat, but you neglect it in such way.

Comment: what is tha best way

Comment: @RomanC the only version in which `escape=false` works and `escapeHtml=false` doesn't is 2.0.x if I remember well. And this means there is a **huge amout of security breaches** and vulnerabilities other than the one opened by unescaped HTML content, namely XSS. He needs to upgrade before worrying about this, IMHO

Comment: @AndreaLigios Do you want to say that `escapeHtml=false` doesn't protect against XSS ( I meant misspelled in above comment)?

Comment: @RomanC `escapeHtml=true` protects against XSS, but in old Struts 2 versions, it wasn't avaiblable, only `escape=true` was available. And since he said that `escapeHtml=false` raised an exception in view (99% jasper) while `escape=false` worked, this means he is using Struts 2.0. And if he is using Struts 2.0, he is vulnerable to more than 20 Big Bugs listed in the Security Bulletin. He should upgrade ASAP, *then* worrying about not disabling the escaping capability (that, we agree, should not be disabled, to remain protected against XSS)

Comment: @AndreaLigios Do you know how escaped content to show in the browser as HTML?

Comment: @RomanC Not sure what you are asking

Comment: If He is using `escapeHtml=true` then he can't add elements to the document, is there a way to modify DOM with escaped HTML? I mean ading html content doesn't work if it's escaped, but how to add it to display correctly if the content is protected against XSS (escaped)?

Comment: There are many ways, for example returning the data into prepared HTML, or generating it with javascript. He could even disable the escaping through a careful XSS filtering serverside. But as said his main problem is not XSS right now, it is instead an uber-compromised struts version needing an upgrade.

Comment: Upgrading Struts is not a big problem, it should be done as usual or using a plan, but to protect against XSS requires significant more effort and if He says disabling escaping capabilities of the property tag works great, it's a very questionable statement.